# creating a single instance of a hash and compare to another hash in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, include

I need to see if a hash is included in another hash in a view. But I'm not sure if I'm creating a hash correctly, when I put "<%= y %>" in the view, It shows all the outputs of y, which makes me think its an array. Usually if its a hash, I would just see "#" right?

I know that x should have y yet I still get "no y is not in x"

```
someview.html.erb

<% x = @books.sifi %>
<% y = { :title => spaceship, :author => mark, :price => 9.99, :genre => sifi} %>

<% if x.include?(y) %>
  yes y is in x
<% else %>
  no y is not in x
<% end %>
```

pretty new to rails so any help would be appreciated!! thanks~!

Comment: This looks like too much logic for a view. Try putting it in a helper.

Comment: Yes, its a lot of logic, but this is tied to an ajax call that refreshes based on a user action, and I need to run this logic on the refresh to determine what is spit out in the view~ is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: It may help you to use the debug helper. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is a hash that you have defined. `x` is most probably an array. Your code is fine in this respect. To determine the class of a object you can do : `<%= y.class %>`.

(I am presuming that *sifi*, *spaceship* etc. are probably not variables in your view? If so, then either put those values in `''` or `""`.)

Comment: spaceship, mark, 9.99 etc... are all variables. when I put <%= x %> in the view, i get "######" and if I do something like <%= x[0][:title] %> it spits out the actual string.. making me believe its a hash..

Comment: Actually, x is an Array of Hash(es). So the x[0] accesses the first hash ("record") in the Array x, and [:title] accesses the value of that key in the Hash.

Comment: so is there no way to compare x and y? I want to check if y-hash exists in the x-array of hashes...

Comment: I already said... your code does that test and it will work fine. Whats the problem ?

Comment: well, I know that the y-hash exists in the x-array of hashes, yet it always says no "y is not in x".. when it should say "yes y is in x"

Comment: Do a `<%= debug x %>` and post the results here - I think the data isn't matching because you are expecting some data in x but it isn't there in the first place. May as well do a `debug y` also..

Comment: Thank you Zabba~~ thats is right, x has values not defined in the y hash. rather than define all the values, because some of the values include ":created_at", ":updated_at", is there away to create a hash for x for just the :title? something like <% x = @books.sifi[:title] %>?

Comment: Yes you can do that like this: `@books.sifi.collect {|el| {:title,el[:title]} }`. This will return to you Array of Hashes and each Hash will have one key (`:title`) and it's value like this : `[{ :title => "title1" },{ :title => "title2" }]`

Comment: TY MUCH Zabba, just for future reference, what is this solution called? I've been trying to google "make array from one attribute collected from each hash in another array rails" lol

Comment: I don't know what it's called :) I recommend you buy the **excellent** book called "The Ruby Way" by Hal Fulton. (BTW, this is the book that the creator of Rails read and was inspired to use Ruby to make Rails :)